# Unexpected end of stream ksoap2-android with gsoap

Tags: android, c++, android-ksoap2, gsoap

We have an android app that uses soap to communicate with an API implemented in C++ with gsoap. The android application uses the ksoap2-android library for soap communications.

When the android app runs on an actual device and communicates over wifi everything seems to work as it should. However when run in the emulater (virtualized x86 image) requests with longer replies often fail with a ProtocolException unexpected end of stream.

This error and because it only tends to happen with long responses let me to the believe that on the gsoap side the socket gets closed to soon. I have tried somethings.

- default accept_flags on the gsoap side didn't work
- explicitly remove SO_LINGER flags from accept_flags in gsoap, didn't solve the issue (I was worried it might set linger with a timeout of zero which would result in exactly my problem)
- explicitly specify the SO_LINGER flag in the accept flags and a timeout of 10, didn't solve the issue
- Then i tried adding a sleep for 1 second right before shutdown in gsoaps tcp_disconnect function. That solved the problem but sleeping is no good ofcourse.

As sleeping is not a good solution I ended up using select which seems to work ok but I'm not 100% confident in this solution.

Here is the actual code change. These are the last lines of the tcp_disconnect function in stdsoap2.cpp. The tcp_select call is what I have added.

```
    if (soap_valid_socket(soap->socket) && !(soap->omode & SOAP_IO_UDP))
    {
        tcp_select(soap, soap->socket, SOAP_TCP_SELECT_RCV | SOAP_TCP_SELECT_ERR, 5);
        soap->fshutdownsocket(soap, soap->socket, SOAP_SHUT_RDWR);
        soap->fclosesocket(soap, soap->socket);
        soap->socket = SOAP_INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

Is this the right solution?